# UNIX : How to move all file inside folder without getting binary operator expected

Tags: bash, unix, mv

I have bash unix script to move all files from folder to another folder.
But, it's always give me binary operation expected when there's more than 1 file in source folder.

My Code goes like this

```
#Variable
NAS_MYTH=/cd/myth_extfile/shyn/
NAS_SHYN=/cd/shyn/MYTH/*

#Script
echo " Move file SHYN to NAS MYTH : $NAS_MYTH"

if [ -f $NAS_SHYN ]; then
 mv $NAS_SHYN $NAS_MYTH
 echo "Success:  moving files to $NAS_MYTH"
else
 echo "Success : No files need to be moved"
fi
```

I'm using if method to check if there is data there, so it'll success error shown
But, this code i use is fine when in folder MYTH there is just one data, but when it's more than one data i'll get error output like this

```
Move file SHYN to NAS MYTH : /cd/myth_extfile/shyn/
./mv_shyn_files.sh: line 52: [: /cd/shyn/MYTH/FAQ - MYTH.pdf: binary operator expected
Sucess : No file need to be move
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

UPDATE

It's all solved, im using this code now

```
shopt -s nullglob
NAS_MYTH=/cd/myth_extfile/shyn/
NAS_SHYN=(/cd/shyn/MYTH/*)

   echo "Checking if there is a file, please wait"

if [ "${#NAS_SHYN[@]}" != 0 ]; then
  echo "There is ${#NAS_SHYN[@]} file"
  mv -f "${NAS_SHYN[@]}" "$NAS_MYTH"
  echo "Success : ${#NAS_SHYN[@]} file moved"
else
  echo "Success : There is no file need to be moved"
fi
```

Thanks guys for helping me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NAS_SHYN=/cd/shyn/MYTH/*` assigns a literal `*` to `NASH_SHYN`. But when you write `$NAS_SHYN` without quotes then the `*` is expanded into a list of files which are then expanended into a list of words by splitting the file names at whitespace. In your case, it seems like there is only one file, namely `FAQ - MYTH.pdf`. However, that file has spaces in it, therefore bash splits your filename into multiple words causing the error.

Instead, use an array and quote your variables.

```
shopt -s nullglob
NAS_SHYN=(/cd/shyn/MYTH/*)

if [ "${#NAS_SHYN[@]}" != 1 ]; then
  echo "expected one match but found ${#NAS_SHYN[@]}"
  exit 1
fi
echo "The only match is ${#NAS_SHYN[0]}"

if [ -f "${NAS_SHYN[0]}" ]; then
  …
```

By the way ALLCAPS variables are by convention special or environment variables. To avoid accidental name collisions use lowercase variables instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this one give me output, 
Move file SHYN to NAS MYTH : /cd/myth_extfile/shyn/
expected one match but found 2
and i adding if below with my mv command, but no luck.
I just want to move all 2 file into target folder using bash script, cause i'll run automatically 10 min cyclic,

Comment: `if ((${NAS_SHYN [@]})); then
 mv "${NAS_SHYN[@]}" "$NAS_MYTH"
 echo "Success:  moving files to $NAS_MYTH"
else
 echo "Success : No files need to be moved"
fi
`